# NT Divisibility with Primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p,q > 3$ be primes. Prove that $(p-1)(q-1) \mid (pq)^2 + 3$ has no solutions.

This is the last part needed for a problem of a math competition and I'm looking for other solutions than in the official solutions. So any ideas would be nice! :)

Comment: It reminds me of Lehmer's totient problem, i.e., that $\phi(pq)=(p-1)(q-1)\mid pq-1$ has no solution. On the other hand, this has solutions, e.g., $(p,q)=(3,7)$.

Comment: Indeed, the original problem asked the contestant to solve $\varphi(n) \mid n^2 + 3$ for natural $n$.

Comment: I can only find $n=1,2,3,4,5,9,21$ for this.

Comment: $4$ is probably a typo, right? As that is not an answer. But yeah, the difficult part is the part I posted, I believe.

Comment: I see, the "official solution" is at [problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1225696s1_phin_divides_n2__3), in case someone has spend time on this question. I believe, the solution there is very natural, and cannot really be improved. Any "other" solution would have been very similar.

Comment: Allowing $p = 2$ would make it much too easy...